# PHP glob select multiple folders

Tags: php, file, directory, glob

How can I get a listing of all images having specific extension from multiple folders using the PHP glob() function?

```
$images = glob("data/{'./assets/img/post/birthday-wishes/*.png','./assets/img/post/birthday-quotes/*.png'}/*", GLOB_BRACE);
echo $images;
```

Comment: What happens when you execute the above code? Also, what happens if you remove the single quotes `'`?

Comment: @kiner_shah it throws error : Array to string conversion in array

Comment: Do you get the error after removing single quotes or without removing them?

Comment: @kiner_shah error remains same in both cases

Comment: I notice `/*` at the end of the string before `GLOB_BRACE`. Please check if that's a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple asterisks with the glob() function

```
$images = glob('./assets/img/post/*/*.png');
print_r($images);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if helpful

```
$images = glob("data/{assets/img/post/birthday-wishes/*.png,assets/img/post/birthday-quotes/*.png}", GLOB_BRACE);
echo $images;
```

Comment: Please explain what changes have you done.

Comment: I remove /* from last & also single quotes

Comment: @RahulRajput it is throwing error Notice: Array to string conversion in array

Comment: This code working fine for listing of  specific extension from multiple folders

$results=glob("test/{chatapp/*.php,chatphp/*.php}",GLOB_BRACE);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($results);